# to avoid reading an rss node that is not present in the feed

Tags: c#, linq, rss

I am reading an rss feed which has "credit" node in my item in most of the cases. While in some case it is not there..how do I avoid getting object not set exception?
I am reading it this way using linq in c#

```
Credit = (string)item.Element(media + "credit").Value == null ? string.Empty : (string)item.Element(media + "credit").Value,
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if element is not null before retrieving elements value:

```
var creditElement = item.Element(media + "credit");
Credit = (creditElement == null) ? string.Empty : (string)creditElement.Value;
```

But Linq is smart enough - it can explicitly cast element value to string and treat missing element as null. So you can just convert element to string, and with null coalescing operator assign default value:

```
Credit = (string)item.Element(media + "credit") ?? String.Empty;
```